# Filter() formula is stopping conditonal format from working

Tags: google-sheets

I have a filter() formula in cell A1 which I want to be red if the cell is empty.

The problem is the cell is always populated because of the formula in the cell.  Is there anyway round this?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional formatting rule *format cells if... is empty* will highlight a cell when it is truly blank or only contains whitespace. It does not make a difference whether the cell contains a hand-entered value or a formula.

When a `filter()` formula gets zero results, the formula cell will display an `#N/A` error. Error cells are not considered empty. To make the formula cell truly empty in the event of zero results, and let your conditional formatting rule work the way you want, use the `iferror(filter())` pattern.